# Explain output of following C program

Tags: c, operator-keyword, operator-precedence, associativity

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
int a=1;
printf("%d %d %d %d %d\n",++a,a++,++a,++a,a++);
a=1;
printf("%d %d %d %d %d",a,a++,a,++a,a);
}
```

When I run it , it gives following output.

```
6 4 6 6 1
3 2 3 3 3
```

Please explain the  code.

Comment: **Undefined behavior**. [Read this **carefully** if you want to know why.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points)

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: I am new to C language... Please explain me the code..It is not a homework...

Comment: @user1521160 Explanations need definition behind them. There is no definitive behavior here. The order of expression evaluation for each of those function parameter terms is *not* defined, and thus neither is the behavior. **See the first comment above.**. This code could just as easily spawn a new form of bacteria in your DVD-drive when you ran it. Thus the nature of *undefined*.

Comment: As well as reading WhozCraig's link, you should probably read up on operator precedence and associativity as well - you've added them as tags, but they have nothing to do with this code.

Comment: Thanks all for the help!!!Understood!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of evaluation of function arguments is not defined, so the `++` operators could be applied in any order.  You're looking at the results of undefined behaviour.